# How to send WebSocketSubject messages only from client to server?

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs

I created an observable for my websocket connection using WebSocketSubject from rxjs. So far so good the server-client communication is working. Now the thing is: I can't distinguish between the origins of the message in my client. I send messages by calling next() on the subject. All subscriptions on the client get those messages too. How can I send messages only to the server instead?

The implementation mainly stems from this article: https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-websocket-node-31f421c753ff

My code:

```
socket$: WebSocketSubject<any>;

constructor() {
  this.socket$ = WebSocketSubject.create(SOCKET_URL);

  this.socket$.subscribe(
    (message) => console.log('<-- ' + message),
    (err) => console.error('Error on WebSocket:', err),
    () => console.warn('Completed!')
   );
}

send(message: SocketMessage) {
  const tmp: any = {};
  tmp.type = message.type;
  tmp.payload = message.payload;
  // This will be received by the server but also by client subscriptions = bad
  this.socket$.next(JSON.stringify(tmp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution trying to have your described behavior :

[RxJS6's WebSocket's documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/webSocket.ts#L41) states that

> Calling `next` does not affect subscribers of `WebSocketSubject` - they have no information that something was sent to the server (unless of course the server responds somehow to a message).

Thus, by using RxJS **6** instead of RxJS **5** you should not have the described behavior.

Comment: This does not work for me. Having the described behavior with rxjs 6.6. Even if the subscribers are not notified until a message is received I think the described issue is to only send a message, which kind of defies the approach of taking a subject in the first place IMO